# Field value not coming in template.php for published node

Tags: theming

I am trying below code to get node field value into template.php.

```
$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_read_more_title');
$variables['readmoretitle'] = $field_items[0]['value'];
```

But $variables['readmoretitle'] is empty for published node, for unpublished node I am getting correct value.

How can I get the published node field value in template.php?

Comment: What function are you doing this code?

Comment: In hook_preprocess_node().

Comment: Can you copy the whole function?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to doing this is `hook_node_view_alter(&$build)` where you can alter teaser link or any other $links. You reference from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1844292)